# How to use Selenium to fine elements based on specific class name text

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm newer to python/selenium, and I'm trying to web scrape a bovada website for live odds. My goal is to use the [pga website](https://www.bovada.lv/sports/golf/pga-tour) to retrieve the 'outright live' odds. However, in dealing with the html, there are numerous types of odds on the page.

I'm trying to retrieve the odds only for the [Outright Live odds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PsOO.png). I'm not interested in scraping the odds for other categories (2 chances, 3 chances, 2nd round leader [screenshot for list of odds on page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMgsL.png)).

I'm having issues organizing my lists and creating the dataframe to display only the 'outright live bet' with the right player/odds. For emample, my output is displaying all the players and odds for each type of bet from website, but I only want to see the odds for the 'outright live' bets. My idea was to use a if-then statement like (if browser.find_elements('class name','market-name') = 'Outright Live' then 'do this') but that doesn't work.

I included my code below. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://www.bovada.lv/sports/golf/pga-tour"

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://www.bovada.lv/sports/golf/pga-tour")
browser.implicitly_wait(5)

#get elements based on their class names
title = browser.find_elements('class name','market-header')
heading = browser.find_elements('class name','game-heading')
bet_Type = browser.find_elements('class name','market-name')
player = browser.find_elements('class name', 'outcomes')
odds_player = browser.find_elements('class name','bet-price')

#lists to store data
titleList = []
betTypeList = []
playerList = []
oddsList = []

for i in range(len(bet_Type)):
    betTypeList.append(bet_Type[i].text)

print(betTypeList)

for i in range(len(player)):
    playerList.append(player[i].text)
    oddsList.append(odds_player[i].text)
    titleList.append(title[0].text)

print(playerList)
print(oddsList)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below locators to retrieve the names and bet-price:

For names:

```
.//*[text()=' Outright Live ']//ancestor::div[2]//span[@class='outcomes']
```

For bet-price:

```
.//*[text()=' Outright Live ']//ancestor::div[2]//span[@class='bet-price']
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! Could you expand more on how we would use these indicators? When I try to use "browser.find_elements('class name',("//*[text()='Outright']//ancestor::div[2]//span[@class='outcomes']"))" it's not working.

Comment: this is xpath - quite a powerful syntax to indicate elements. check how to use xpath with selenium https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Comment: You have to learn how to identify and write the simplest form of locators - which is the most important concept for Selenium. You can refer the below sites:   https://www.swtestacademy.com/xpath-selenium/ ,  https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/xpath-in-selenium/  ,  https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/complete-guide-for-using-xpath-in-selenium-with-examples/

Comment: If this answer works for you, mark that as the answer.

Comment: sorry for the delay but this solution is still not working for me.